# Can FlutterLogo be made to stretch-to-fill?

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to display a large FlutterLogo in my app:
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/FlutterLogo-class.html

In order to account for varying screen sizes I would like to make it stretch-to fill.  Is that possible?  Or do I need to use a MediaQuery to determine the parent's size and pass that into FlutterLogo(size:)?

My current code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
      child: new FlutterLogo(size: 800.0, style: FlutterLogoStyle.horizontal, textColor: Colors.white),
    );
  }
```

Comment: This post may be of help


  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45817007/how-to-automatically-size-icons-in-flutter-to-be-as-big-as-possible

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I believe I have answered a similar question

[How to stretch an icon to fill parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45299847/how-to-stretch-an-icon-to-fill-parent/45340109#45340109)

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/flutter-dev/lsgdU1yl7xc/0pYS2qrzBQAJ

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html

```
 new Expanded(
      child: new FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        child: new FlutterLogo( style: FlutterLogoStyle.horizontal, textColor: Colors.white),
      ),
  ),
```

I feel kinda strange. Looking at the OP profile ID, I wonder if I answer the question correctly.

I hope this helps.

used this code to run it

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  MyAppBar({this.title});

  // Fields in a Widget subclass are always marked "final".

  final Widget title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      height: 56.0, // in logical pixels
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue[500]),
      // Row is a horizontal, linear layout.
      child: new Row(
    // <Widget> is the type of items in the list.
    children: <Widget>[
      new IconButton(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.menu),
        tooltip: 'Navigation menu',
        onPressed: null, // null disables the button
      ),
      // Expanded expands its child to fill the available space.
      new Expanded(
        child: title,
      ),
      new IconButton(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
        tooltip: 'Search',
        onPressed: null,
      ),
    ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Material is a conceptual piece of paper on which the UI appears.
    return new Material(
      // Column is a vertical, linear layout.
      child: new Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      new MyAppBar(
        title: new Text(
          'Example title',
          style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.title,
        ),
      ),
      new Expanded(
        child: new FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          child: new FlutterLogo( style: FlutterLogoStyle.horizontal, textColor: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: 'My app', // used by the OS task switcher
    home: new MyScaffold(),
  ));
}
```

edit: I posted complete code just for darky, since I forgot to mention that expanded needs to be wrapped into row, column, or flex container to expand

Comment: Won't work. While the the container will get properly sized, the icon won't (and will be centered).

Comment: @Darky

strange i tested the code above and the icon filled the parent.

Comment: @user142442 ah, seems like FlutterLogo act differently then the usual Icon Widget. So my bad, forget it.

Comment: @Darky No, It my fault, I should had just tested the snippet or added the complete code. The icon fill acts the same way as the Icon Widget. The fill depends on the Box fit class.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html

I am looking at collin's solution and wondering if my solution is more flexible than his or just plain different.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a `ConstrainedBox`:

[image: screenshot]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      theme: new ThemeData.dark(),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Example App')),
      body: new ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: new FlutterLogo(
          style: FlutterLogoStyle.horizontal,
          textColor: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```